# Powershell import-csv anad get the latest date

Tags: powershell

I'm importing a CSV file and I need to return the most recent logged in date for a specific hostname. Any ideas? I've been trying to group objects and run a for-each on them but I can't manage to pull the latest. Here's an example of the data:

e.g. for mypc1 I want to return an object that includes the hostname, username and also the date of the latest login. In this case 2022-08-15 07:51:51.

| Computer Name | Username | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mypc1 | jcitizen | 2022-07-06 18:00:20 |
| mypc1 | bmcgee | 2022-08-15 07:51:51 |
| mypc1 | jmarsh | 2021-05-25 12:49:14 |
| mypc2 | jmarsh | 2022-08-12 07:45:55 |
| mypc2 | jsmith | 2022-03-12 07:00:07 |
| mypc3 | osmith | 2022-08-08 08:36:03 |
| mypc3 | moliver | 2022-08-08 07:37:27 |

Comment: Post your code and we can help you - however you may find more joy using `Sort-Object` as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821752/powershell-sort-object-by-datetimeparseexact

Comment: @Scepticalist https://codeshare.io/dwlvzZ